# Magento Shopping Cart Rules Buy X get 10% off everything

Tags: magento, e-commerce

I'm having some problems getting my Magento Cart Rules to apply.

What I am trying to do is encourage users to purchase gift cards, so if you purchase a gift card you get 10% off the entire transaction assuming you purchase 2 or more items (including the gift card).

This is what I am using at the moment:

In Conditions

```
If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE :

Total Items Quantity  equals or greater than  2 
If an item is FOUND  in the cart with ANY  of these conditions true:
    SKU  is  7667  (Gift Card)
```

In Actions

```
Apply             Fixed amount discount for whole cart
Discount Amount       10
```

All the rest are as default.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Refer to this : http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/what-are-shopping-cart-price-rules-and-how-do-i-use-them

Comment: Hi, I read through this prior to posting here, however it was no help in achieving what I want to achieve. Thanks for your suggestion though!

Answer (score 0):

Your conditions seem to be correct. But in actions you have defined a fixed amount discount instead of a percent discount.

In Actions:

```
Apply Percent of product price discount
Discount Amount 10
```

Also you have to keep in mind that this way someone could simply put 2 giftcards in his cart to get the discount. You should add another rule check for an item where SKU IS NOT 7667.